# "Can I run X game that is Only-Windows game in Ubuntu?" we need a canonical question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions, canonical-answer

Latelly I got the felling that we are now the WineHQ site, where people can ask "will X game run in Ubuntu?". I would love make them check the WineHQ, or ask the makers if they have a Linux version and *then* ask here if they have a specific problem, instead of:

- asking if it will run
- we say yes
- they try to play
- find a problem
- ask another question, being all bitter because we told him he could play
- we tell him how to solve the problem.

I try to make those 6 steps into just 1. Any in favor? Who is in disagreement?

Comment: Do we not already have a generic QA for Windows applications?

Comment: @oli I tried to find one, with several views/linked questions for "games" (seems that if the canonical question don't include that word, nobody flags them as duplicated), and found none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not contain the word "games" but it applies (and already exists):

- [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software)

I don't think we need to denormalise "Windows software" to every type of application. Especially when we'd be using exactly the same answer.

Comment: Yeah, this would be way easier.

Comment: Flagging away!!